# Keep getting [object HTMLLIElement] when trying to add element to the page

Tags: javascript, oop, javascript-objects

This code shows `[object HTMLLIElement]` instead of the actual click element. when I `console.log` `this` variable it gives me the elements I want to show in the page but in the page itself it shows `[object HTMLLIElement]`

```
var mainView = {
  liDis: function() {
    var liList = oct.catsList().getElementsByTagName('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
      liList[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        console.log(this);
        oct.catsDisplay().innerHTML = this.value;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `value` is not a property of `li` elements..`innerHTML = this....` will not add but replace element...

Comment: Not sure of the answer, but any reason this is related to 'functional-programming'?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get element-initiator of the event then you shall use `event.target` property:

```
  liList[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    oct.catsDisplay().innerHTML = event.target.value;
  });
```

So if you have button inside that `<li>` element and on click on it you will get it in `event.target`.

Comment: There could be many elements in `li` element...And OP may want to deal with only Button...

Comment: Ummm, `if( event.target.tag == "button" ) ...`  then.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I was able to do it was by using jQuery :

```
liDis: function () { 
                 $(document).on('click', 'li', function (e) {
                     e.preventDefault();
                     score = 0;
                    var jjjj = $(this).html();
                    $( "#catsDisplay" ).html( jjjj + "<br><p id='score'>" + 0 + "</p>");
                 })
    }
```